NCN 9 between Halden and Vestmarka routing alternatives
Between Halden (Østfold) and Vestmarka (Eidskog, Innlandet) in Norway, Norwegian National Cycling Route 9 (Villmarksveien) has a main route following County Road 21 via Fjell, Aremark, Ørje, and Rømsjøen and an alternate route following county routes 1334, 1324, 1318, 124, 1316, 128, 1308, 123, 1450, 125, 1454, 1465, 1466 via Rød, Strømsfoss, Hemnes, and Bjørkelangen.  Further north, they run together up to Trysil, where markings end and the remaining route is merely proposed.  Although the alternate route is marked as proposed on Openstreetmap, signage exists here as well.
What are some characteristic differences between the two routes?  I speculate the alternate route has less traffic.  For example, County Road 1324 might be less busy than County Road 21, and on Streetview, County Road 1316 at times look narrower than County Road 21.  But neither route looks very busy and maybe the surface is better on the main route.  Or maybe the alternate route is more scenic, and the main route is cheaper/lazier signposting, following a single road.  Has anyone ridden both and can advice?

Question is too localised and specific and will benefit only a tiny minority of users. For the purpose of discouraging “Is this local route better than another local route” type of question I’m voting to close. Nothing personal @ OP

@WarrenBurton "Too localised" was retired as a closing reason in 2013.  This question can benefit all bicycle tourers in southeastern Norway.

I haven't ridden either of those routes, but I think all your conjectures should rather be the other way around. I reckon the alternative has likely more boring parts, and probably more traffic - both more traffic between the nearby Norwegian towns, and the traffic of Norwegians shuttling over the border to buy booze - whereas the main route with its more winding and largely border-parallel direction isn't very practical for car drivers.
